# How to lopp through multiple elements and add the content to a string

Tags: cypress

I would like to loop through a list of elements and store the value of an attribute in a string, which I can for example store as ALIAS for use later.
Something like:

For example a table with some titles in a header:

```
let headerstr = '';
cy.get(`table tr th`)
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
      const str = $list[index].getAttribute('data-e2e-table-column');
      headerstr += headerstr + str +';';
});
```

This does obviously not work, as the headerstr is not filled outside the loop.

(Background is that the test should do some column reordering in a table and verify that the order is different)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to extract header attributes, then use nested calls to  `cy.get('table tr th')`

```js
const getHeaderAttrs = ($headers) => {
  const attrs = [...$headers].map(h => h.getAttribute('data-e2e-table-column'))
  return attrs.join(';')
}

cy.get('table tr th')
  .then(getHeaderAttrs)
  .then(headerstr1 => {

    // reorder columns

    cy.get('table tr th')
      .then(getHeaderAttrs)
      .then(headerstr2 => {
        expect(headerstr1).to.not.eq(headerstr2)
      })
  })
```

Comment: Thank. This works. Howver, there is eslint complaining: Unsafe spread of an any value in an array.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment for the [...$headers] in the getHeaderAttrs